# Move selected file

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a Swift macOS application, and I'm trying to allow the user to open a file using `NSOpenPanel` and then rename that file to another name.

I have enabled sandboxing with `User Selected File` set to Read/Write.

Here is my code:

```
let panel = NSOpenPanel()
panel.canChooseFiles = true
panel.canChooseDirectories = false
panel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
if panel.runModal() == .OK {
    let url = panel.url!
    
    do {
        try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url, to: url.deletingLastPathComponent().appendingPathComponent("New name.test"))
    }
    catch let x {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

It simply asks the user to choose a file, and then renames the file to `"New name.test"`. However, I get an error message saying

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“Untitled” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “untitled folder 30”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder 30/Untitled.txt, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSDestinationFilePath=/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder 30/New name.test, NSFilePath=/Users/user/Desktop/untitled folder 30/Untitled.txt, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000032115c0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}
```

I'm pretty sure this is because even though I have access to that specific file, I do not have access to its parent directory which is what I need in order to rename the file.

This question is very similar to [Application Sandbox: renaming a file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950476/application-sandbox-renaming-a-file-doesnt-work), however none of the answers work for me.

The most promising answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16362053/16324343), and I tried adding the document types & using `NSFileCoordinator`, but it still didn't work, with this error:

```
an error was received from pboxd instead of a token. Domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: 1
```

Is this even possible, or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Application Sandbox: renaming a file doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950476/application-sandbox-renaming-a-file-doesnt-work)

Comment: @Willeke Not quite. I tried the 1 solution posted, but with no luck

Comment: You can't do that.  A possible way is to open a specific file with `NSOpenPanel` and then use `NSSavePanel` to select a folder or a volume where to save the file.

Comment: As @ElTomato wrote. NSSavePanel gives you access to only one file. NSOpenPanel + canChooseFiles -> gives you access to that file. NSOpenPanel + canChooseDirectories gives you access to all items in the folder (including move or new files). Try this code and it works: let newUrl = url.appendingPathComponent("New name.test")
                let url = url.appendingPathComponent("1232466.jpg") try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: url, to: newUrl) with NSOpenPanel  + canChooseDirectories

Comment: Discussion
When copying items, the current process must have permission to read the file or directory at srcPath and write the parent directory of dstPath. If the item at srcPath is a directory, this method copies the directory and all of its contents, including any hidden files. If a file with the same name already exists at dstPath, this method stops the copy attempt and returns an appropriate error. If the last component of srcPath is a symbolic link, only the link is copied to the new path.

Comment: Solutions: 1. Drop, or radically loosen, the App Sandbox (not possible for app store) 2. Present the user with a save panel for the output.  Have a look at Keka.app. It only allows drag&drop on icon or app window (this way or NSOpenPanel) and ask for new filename using NSSavePanel. Another solution would be right click "Open with"

Comment: @MarekH canChooseDirectories does not fix the problem. It only works if you select that entire directory, but if you have canChooseDirectories and canChooseFiles and the user chooses a file, it wont work

Comment: This is how sandbox is designed. Read my post again. It CANNOT be fixed just by one liner

Comment: @MarekH Did you select the directory or just the file?

Comment: This is how sandbox is designed. Read my post again. It CANNOT be fixed just by one liner –

Comment: @MarekH yeah, thats kinda what I thought. Oh well (i guess the user just has to choose the directory)

Comment: please try to learn to read. You reject other people help with "doesn't work" instead of trying to understand what we are saying

Comment: @MarekH Your right, I apologize. I should've mentioned I cant really use `NSSavePanel` because for my case, I will be processing potentially hundreds of files at once. (all in different directories)

Comment: If you get access with nsopenpanel to a folder -> no need to use NSSavePanel. Most  solutions utilize drag&drop together with NSOpenPanel (e.g. disabled users need it). Many apps are not on the app store due to sandboxing. It can be disabled. You can read some frustration https://mjtsai.com/blog/2012/09/23/aperture-3-4-sandboxing-and-flickrexport/

Comment: Also you can use Security-Scoped Bookmarks and Persistent Resource Access https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW16 Great example is DaisyDisk.app It just ask once to select whole drive and it can access all files even after reboot

Comment: @MarekH Thanks for the suggestions, however for my scenario I really cant disable sandboxing. Security-Scoped Bookmarks and such will help, but the user still has to select the folder first.

Comment: Note that you can select the directory prior to this operation. You can have a button to select target folder in your UI, so they save/open dialogs don't get shown one after another. I actually don't see a sensible situation where you would want to move the files anywhere outside the sandbox container without user consent. You can also move the files into a temporary directory first and take care of the actual moving later.

Comment: @Tritonal I'm actually not moving the files, just renaming. Basically the user will select some files to perform an operation on, and the app will rename those files